# NSFetchedResultsController for PickerView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my `UIViewController` i have `NSFetchedResultsController` for `TableView`. Now i want to add new for `UIPickerView` to delegate add/edit/delete events and change items in `UIPickerView`. How can i do this? I din't find any tutorial with `NSFetchedResultsController` and `UIPickerView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use common sense in using the fetched results controller's methods in the `datasource` methods of the `UIPickerView`.

E.g. `fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count`
for  `pickerView(_:numberOfRowsInComponent:)` and `fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath:)`
for the actual object to be displayed in a row via
`viewForRow(_:forComponent:)`.

I suppose for several components you would need several fetched results controllers. Please note that as far as I remember, according to the HIG the maximum number of items in a `UIPickerView` should not exceed 20 or so.

Comment: See above. I included enough information in the answer to implement this. What else do you need?